# no BSODs under windows 10

Tags: windows-10, kernel, driver, bsod

I am doing driver development and try to force a BSOD on windows 10 latest running in VirtualBox. But it's not possible, I can only get immediate autorestarts or permanent freezes (depending on the auto-restart setting in advanced system settings), but no actual Blue Screen.

I have tried a) doing buggy things in my driver b) calling KeBugCheck() in my driver c) using NotMyFault by Sysinternals.

How can I force a Blue Screen?

Comment: Random thought but have you tried enabling HaltOnReset? See 12.3.5 of https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#idm10260

Comment: thanks, but this also just causes a hang...